# A* Search Advantages of Dynamic Weighting

Tags: search, a-star

I was reading about the variants of the A* search algorithm and I came across dynamic weighting. As I understand it, a weight is applied to the search equation, which decreases as the search gets closer to the goal node. I was specifically looking at this article : http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Variations.html

Can anyone tell me what the advantages of this would be? Why would you not care what nodes you expand at the start? Is it to help searches that don't necessarily have a good heuristic?

Thanks

Comment: You may have better luck asking on cstheory.stackexchange.com or cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### For the TLDNR-crowd:

Dynamic weighting sacrifices solution optimality to speed up the search. The larger the weight, the more greedy the search.

### For my fellow scholars:

#### Motivation

*From the Wikipedia A-star article:*
A-star's admissibility criterion guarantees an optimal solution path, but it also means that A* must examine *all* equally meritorious paths to find the optimal path. We can speed up the search at the expense of optimality by relaxing the admissibility criterion to obtain an approximate solution. Oftentimes we want to bound this relaxation, so that we can guarantee that the solution path is no worse than (1 + ε) times the optimal solution path. This new guarantee is referred to as ε-admissible.

#### Static Weighting

Before we talk about dynamic weighting, let's compare A-star to the simplest ε-admissible relaxation: static-weighted A-star.

In static-weighted A-star,  f(n) = g(n) + w·h(n), with w=(1+ε) for some ε>0. To illustrate the effect on optimality and search speed, compare the number of nodes expanded in each of the following illustrations. Empty circles represent nodes in the *open set*; filled-in circles are in the *closed set*.

[image: A-star] [image: Static weighted A-star with weight 4.0(=epsilon)]

**A-star (left) vs. Weighted A-star with ε=4 (right)**

As you can see, weighted A-star expanded far fewer nodes and completed about 3x as fast. However, since we used ε=4, weighted A-star could theoretically return a solution that is (1+ε)=(1+4)=5x times as long as the optimal path.

#### Dynamic Weighting

Dynamic Weighting is a technique that makes the heuristic weight a function of the search state, i.e. f(n) = g(n) + w(n)·h(n), where w(n) = (1 + ε - (ε*d(n))/N), d(n) is the depth of the current search and N is an upper bound on the search depth.

In this way, dynamic-weight A-Star initially behaves very much like a Greedy Best First search, but as the search depth (i.e. the number of hops in the graph) increases, the algorithm takes a more conservative approach, behaving more like the traditional A-star algorithm.

[Amit Patel's page](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/GameProgramming/Variations.html#dynamic-weighting) says

> With dynamic weighting, you assume that at the beginning of your
> search, it’s more important to get (anywhere) quickly; at the end of
> the search, it’s more important to get to the goal.

He is correct, but I would saythat with dynamic weighting, you assume that at the beginning of your search, it's more important to follow your heuristic; at the end of the search, it becomes equally important to consider the length of the path, too.

### Additional Materials and Links:

1. Asst. Prof. Ira Pohl -- [*The Avoidance of (Relative)
   Catastrophe, Heuristic Competence, Genuine DYnamic Weighting and
   Computational Issues in Heuristic Problem Solving*](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci709s2c/resources/Mike.d/Pohl1973WeightedAStar.pdf)
2. [Dynamic Weighting](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/GameProgramming/Variations.html#dynamic-weighting) on Amit Patel's Variants of A*
3. Wikipedia -- [Bounded Relaxation for the A* Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#/media/File:Astar_progress_animation.gif)

Comment: Is there any way of getting rid off N (upper bound on the search depth)? In general case, when I cannot say anything about the anticipated length of the solution.

Comment: @Pavel Tyshevskyi sorta... Try using a "generalized logistic function" on d(n) instead of just d(n)/N. With a bit of scaling/translation you can avoid the problem of having a hard limit N, but 1. you will likely lose the epsilon optimality property, and 2. You will still have a 'soft' limit implicitly defined by the parameters/shape of the logistic function

Comment: I see, I was looking into this, but you're right, I'm still implicitly defining asymptotic limit by the logistic function parameters. Is there any way of getting rid of this, too? It's likely that A* is not used for this, but I haven't managed to find what to use instead.